# Context Navigation Styling: Sticky Prop Always False

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, next-router

I've set up a context to manage navigation, where the navigation should be styled differently depending on whether it's on the home page (no props) or not (with a prop called isSticky). However, even when it's not on the home page, the value of my `isSticky` prop always remains false. I'm new to using context, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**NavBarContext**

```
"use client";
import React, {
  createContext,
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useLayoutEffect,
} from "react";

// Define the context interface for type safety
interface NavBarContextProps {
  isSticky: boolean;
  setIsSticky: (newState: boolean) => void;
}

// Create the context with the defined interface
export const NavBarContext = createContext<NavBarContextProps>({
  isSticky: false,
  setIsSticky: () => {},
});

// NavBarProvider component with type annotations
export const NavBarProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  // Log initial state value
  const [isSticky, setIsSticky] = useState(() => {
    console.log(
      "Initial isSticky state:",
      typeof window !== "undefined"
        ? window.location.pathname !== "/"
          ? true
          : false
        : false
    );
    return typeof window !== "undefined"
      ? window.location.pathname !== "/"
        ? true
        : false
      : false; // Default to non-sticky for SSR
  });

  const handleStickyNav = () => {
    // Update state for all pages except home for initial stickiness
    if (window.location.pathname !== "/") {
      setIsSticky(true);
    } else {
      // Update state only on home page for scroll-based behavior
      if (window.scrollY > 100) {
        setIsSticky(true);
      } else {
        setIsSticky(false);
      }
    }
  };

  // Client-side update on initial render (including initial sticky state)
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    handleStickyNav();
    console.log("isSticky after handleStickyNav (initial):", isSticky);
  }, []);

  // Update state on every navigation (client-side)
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleNavigation = () => {
      handleStickyNav();
      console.log("isSticky after handleNavigation:", isSticky);
    };

    window.addEventListener("popstate", handleNavigation); // For back/forward buttons
    return () => window.removeEventListener("popstate", handleNavigation);
  }, []);

  return (
    <NavBarContext.Provider value={{ isSticky, setIsSticky }}>
      {children}
    </NavBarContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**NavBar**

```
"use client";
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import Logo from "./logo";
import NavList from "./navlist/navList";
import ResNavItem from "./navlist/resNavItem";
import NavRight from "./navlist/navRight";
import { NavBarContext } from "@/app/contexts/navBarContext";

export default function NavBar() {
  const { isSticky } = useContext(NavBarContext);

  return (
    <nav
      className={`${
        isSticky ? "bg-white" : ""
      }  fixed z-[99] w-full top-0 left-0 flex items-center justify-between py-[20px] sm:px-5xl px-md`}
    >
      <Logo sticky={isSticky} />
      <NavList sticky={isSticky} />
      <NavRight sticky={isSticky} />
      <ResNavItem sticky={isSticky} />
    </nav>
  );
}
```

**Layout**

```
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { DM_Sans } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import NavBar from "@/components/layout/navbar/navBar";
import Footer from "@/components/layout/footer/footer";
import { NavBarProvider } from "./contexts/navBarContext";

const font = DM_Sans({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Mobile Apps Development Software Company Jacksonville fl - RCK",
  description:
    "Mobile application development company in Jacksonville fl. Your's mobile apps Developement Platform run smoothly in all devices and unique Design applications Software,",
  keywords:
    "mobile apps development firm in Jacksonville,mobile apps developers in florida,mobile application development services florida,mobile application development Jacksonville,business mobile application creation in Jacksonville",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={font.className}>
        <NavBarProvider>
          <NavBar />
          <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center">
            {children}
          </main>
          <Footer />
        </NavBarProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```